# How to inform about fields in a big form?

Tags: usability, gui-design, color, warnings

I have to improve a very big form with at lot of fields. I'm thinking about making some type of marking to inform the user about:
1. Fields that should be filled
2. Mandatory fields
3. Content that do not fit in the expected frame

There is no space for nice icons, therefore I'm thinking about colors..

What is the best way to help users in such a situation?

Comment: Do you have a mockup you can provide of your current interface?

Comment: A standard form has two types of fields: optional and required. Is your point #1 an optional field that you'd *really* like them to fill in? I don't know at all what point #3 is referring to...

Comment: What's the difference between a field that should be filled and a mandatory field?

Comment: I don't have much information to give an informed answer. What's this form for? Is it registration? Is it a profile update? How long is it? What's it used for?

Comment: Thanks everybody! Sorry but i am not allowed to show a mock up. But it is e.g some type of reporting form with more than 100 fields and they all have to be on one screen (a requirement from the customer).. i know it's not good for the experience but then my question is: How can i improve it more than just chunk the fields?.. with the field types ind mind (1. Fields that should be filled 2. Mandatory fields 3. Content that do not fit in the expected frame)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, you should avoid presenting users with lots of fields at once (all on one screen). It is daunting for a user to be faced with this (unless they are a call centre data entry employee or similar). You need to break the form up into small, manageable tasks that are presented in a logical order. When you break up the form there will be less "clutter" to distract the user, and it will be easier to give visual weight to data entry errors (such as content being too large) and mandatory fields.

A star is the norm for marking mandatory fields.

Using colour alone to give a message to the user is generally not recommended, as many people cannot distinguish between certain colours (colourblindness).

Comment: I'd like to add to this answer where you should avoid presenting fields that are not mandatory. If it isn't necessary to have the user fill the information out, then why is it presentable. I'm also not sure what this form is for, because then that gives more insight as to what to include and exclude.

Comment: @Majo0od You are right that we should avoid presenting unnecessary fields. However most non mandatory fields I have come across are for information that a company (probably for marketing purposes) would like to collect, but they don't want to annoy users by actually forcing them to fill them in. Other times non mandatory fields might be for a piece of info that doesn't apply to all users, but would be annoying for some users if it was not available (e.g. "do you have any special instructions for this package delivery?" or "any other comments?"). We can't avoid presenting these kinds of fields.

Comment: That is true, but where you show them could vary. That's why I needed some additional information. For instance, those marketing fields should be avoided on registration forms but can be presented in user profile pages.

Comment: @Majo0od Yeh, it definitely depends on the specific situation. Will the user come back to the site / be motivated to complete a profile, or is this a one off visit?

Comment: I get what you are saying but my problem is that it is a form with a lot of fields that will be filled differently depending on the task but all fields have to be shown at the same page. There is an error provider that show what have to be filled out to save. Futhermore there is some fields that have to be filled out to complete the form (but it is possible to save without), then we need to indicate that the content deviant from normal and then there is some fields that is recommended to fill out to give the best result.

Answer (score 0):

Grey out the fields that do not require any input. Keeps the others in simple white color.

For mandatory fields, you can put a small star besides the field

The third point depends on the type of data, If some kind of big text is required you can open a separate textbox on clicking the field.

Comment: If fields do not require any input I would also consider hiding them completely, unless they contain text that the user needs to be able to see.